# how to add an opacity fading effect to to the jquery slidetoggle?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to slide up and down a div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle-button").click(function () {
        $(".about").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

I will like to add a fade in and fade out effect to the toggle button.
Any suggestions about how to do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this is to pass the `toggle` value to [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle-button").click(function() {
        $(".about").animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EYmPA/).

Comment: Hi, this works great but I notice it's a little jerky towards the end of the animation - any idea how to fix this?