# Jquery slideToggle transparency issue

Tags: jquery, opacity, slidetoggle

I'm using jquery slideToggle to pull down a panel in my page. The issue is I cannot set the transparency 'off' or (opacity 1) in the sliding  which makes it mixed up with the background content and messes up. I don't want any transparency in my pull down panel. How do I achieve this.

Here is my code,

```
$("#breakdown").click(function(){
   $("#breakdown_panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Where as #breakdown is a button and #breakdown_panel is a div element.

Here is the CSS

```
#breakdown_panel {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-6px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(71,71,71, 1);
    height: 200px;
    display: none;
    width: 400px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is the image of problematic overlap.
http://i50.tinypic.com/35i4w79.jpg

Comment: Could you please replicate your problem in http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Has already been asked on stackoverflow before. Check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672556/how-to-add-an-opacity-fading-effect-to-to-the-jquery-slidetoggle)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will work or not but give it a try.

```
$("#breakdown_panel").toggle("slide")
```

or

```
$("#breakdown_panel").toggle("blind")
```

Comment: Thanks Jignesh, this does the animation differently but it doesn't solve the opacity issue. Here's the screenshot. http://i50.tinypic.com/35i4w79.jpg

Comment: I suspect that's because you are using    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;  try removing that css option. it's worth giving a try. you can always change the toggle animation type according to your need. refer this link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggle/

Comment: Thanks Jignesh, I wonder why Jquery is adding opacity to the slide panels by default or am I missing here something ? Thanks for the demos. It certainly helps.

Comment: OK, I finally figured out the issue. It's not because of the opacity of the contents mixed up with 

the background content. My sliding panel goes underneath of the other panel which is fixed in 

the screen (it's also have the opacity set to 0.5) and through that panel I see the slide down 

panel content.

I have added z-index:99; into my CSS so the slide down panel comes on top of everything.

BTW, big thanks to you for trying me to provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#breakdown").click(function(){

    $("#breakdown_panel").animate({
        opacity:1,
        height: 'toggle'
      }, 2000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
});
```

maybe someone have a simpliest solution.

Comment: Thanks Charles, but strangely this didn't solve the opacity issue. Here is the effect I'm getting. http://i50.tinypic.com/35i4w79.jpg

Comment: oh sorry I forget to mentionned set the default opacity to 0.

Comment: OK, I finally figured out the issue. It's not because of the opacity of the contents mixed up with 

the background content. My sliding panel goes underneath of the other panel which is fixed in 

the screen (it's also have the opacity set to 0.5) and through that panel I see the slide down 

panel content.

I have added z-index:99; into my CSS so the slide down panel comes on top of everything.

BTW, big thanks to you for trying me to provide the solution.

Comment: Maybe for the future this addon or inner feature of firefox can help you https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/tilt/

Comment: Thank  you Charles. This would certainly help and it's a very useful plugin.