# jQuery toggle option?

Tags: jquery

I found out about `toggle` in this thread [how to add an opacity fading effect to to the jquery slidetoggle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672556/how-to-add-an-opacity-fading-effect-to-to-the-jquery-slidetoggle) and I am confused...

```
$(".about").animate({
        height: "toggle",
        opacity: "toggle"
    }, "slow");
```

Where in the world did user find the "toggle" function, selector or what is this, I don't know. Is this CSS specific or jQuery built in magic? Where can I find more about it?

Comment: it is jquery function

Answer (score 0):

just see the jquery information for **animate**

> In addition to numeric values, each property can take the strings
>   'show', 'hide', and 'toggle'. These shortcuts allow for custom hiding
>   and showing animations that take into account the display type of the
>   element. In order to use jQuery's built-in toggle state tracking, the
>   'toggle' keyword must be consistently given as the value of the
>   property being animated.

ref http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

It's an animation property for `animate` method, from the docs:

> In addition to numeric values, each property can take the strings
>   'show', 'hide', and 'toggle'. These shortcuts allow for custom hiding
>   and showing animations that take into account the display type of the
>   element. In order to use jQuery's built-in toggle state tracking, the
>   'toggle' keyword must be consistently given as the value of the
>   property being animated.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/animate/